# Android and Jtwitter

Tags: java, android, twitter

I am trying to connect to twitter, because i am trying to write an app (for the android platfrom) that updates your twitter status. the problem i have is with Oath. I have both Jtwitter and Signpost.

how do i get these below?

JTWITTER_OAUTH_KEY ,JTWITTER_OAUTH_SECRET

I read that you have to register your application. Mine is just a testing application as I am messing around with android right now. Do i still have to register my app?

In "https://dev.twitter.com/apps/create" they are asking me for an "Application Website:"
which I dont have. do i need to have a website to register my application?

is there any easier way to connect to twitter? without oath?

thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **have** to register your application with Twitter [here](https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new) to get your key and secret. You don't have to provide a real website if you're just testing. Make sure you provide real information when you release your application.

I also recommend sticking with OAuth, it's worth it and shouldn't be too complicated to work with. I personally use twitter4j for integration with android which you can find more info on [here](http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html). I'm sure JTwitter is also fine but I cannot comment on it since I never tried it.

Once you get your key and secret, it should be pretty straightforward. If you require further assistance, there are plenty of tutorials you can find around to help you.

Ryan

Answer (score 1):

You really should register on dev.twitter.com for your own oauth key & secret. You *can* use the String constants `Twitter.JTWITTER_OAUTH_KEY` and `Twitter.JTWITTER_OAUTH_SECRET` to access Twitter via the JTwitter account. This is fine for a bit of experimenting, but nothing more: About once a year, someone will abuse this freedom, at which point we change the oauth keys.